# MRZ Passport Parser c# console application

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to the name from the passport MRZ however i'm having difficulties parsing it. I'm trying to get the name. However I'm getting an:-

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Whenever i try to get the name.

Here's where i try to parse

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || name.Length < 44)
                { }

     var nameArraySplit = name.Substring(5).Split(new[] { "<<" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      name =  nameArraySplit.Length >= 2 ? nameArraySplit[1].Replace("<", " ") : nameArraySplit[0].Replace("<", " ");
```

Example of an MRZ 
`GBRTHATCHER0368447211111119718452091
1522044E12566123BUG<<<<<<<<<<<7
CAT<<GRUMPY<MINITE<<<<<<<<<<<<`

Thank you

Comment: What's your expect result when you parser successful?

Comment: The name "Grumpy "

Comment: https://gist.github.com/imranbaloch/4c048d1e0bb615cbe784b73f898957fe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can try `Split` on `"<"` instead of `"<<"`

then get `nameArraySplit[2]`

```
string name = "GBRTHATCHER03684472111111197184520911522044E12566123BUG<<<<<<<<<<<7CAT<<GRUMPY<MINITE<<<<<<<<<<<< ";

var nameArraySplit = name.Substring(5).Split(new[] {"<" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
name = nameArraySplit.Length >= 2 ? nameArraySplit[2] : nameArraySplit[0].Replace("<", " ");
```

*c# online:https://dotnetfiddle.net/HM1WeG*

Comment: "<" is just a fill character in the MRZ, with fields at fixed positions. Better to use Substring to read the positions needed, and get rid of the <s with Replace.

Comment: Works Perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = @"GBRTHATCHER03684472111111197184520911522044E12566123BUG<<<<<<<<<<<7CAT<<GRUMPY<MINITE<<<<<<<<<<<<";
string name = Regex.Match(input, @"(?i)([a-z]+)<[a-z]+<+?$").Groups[1].Value;
```